# AWS Cognito SDK token expiration

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, session, token, amazon-cognito

I am using Amazon Cognito Mobile SDK to sign into my app (https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/tree/master/AmazonCognitoYourUserPoolsDemo).

The app constantly retrieves data from DynamoDB (every 5 seconds).

However after roughly an hour, when trying to make a call to DynamoDB, the token expires and the SDK does not seem to refresh the token and I received the NotAuthorizedException exception as seen below.

How should I deal with token expiration? Thanks!

```
05-25 15:27:25.282 2540-3428/com.test.example D/AWSRefreshingCognitoIdentityProvider: Refreshing token...
05-25 15:27:25.282 2540-3428/com.test.example D/CognitoUserPoolsSignInProvider: cognito-idp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/eu-west-1_pHznonQVB
05-25 15:27:26.718 2540-3428/com.test.example E/CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider: Failure to get credentials
                                                                                                 com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentity.model.NotAuthorizedException: Invalid login token. Token expired: 1495725747 >= 1495723433 (Service: AmazonCognitoIdentity; Status Code: 400; Error Code: NotAuthorizedException; Request ID: a91e8404-415e-11e7-8a00-bd0979d3092f)
                                                                                                     at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:720)
                                                                                                     at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:394)
                                                                                                     at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:200)
                                                                                                     at com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentity.AmazonCognitoIdentityClient.invoke(AmazonCognitoIdentityClient.java:558)
                                                                                                     at com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentity.AmazonCognitoIdentityClient.getOpenIdToken(AmazonCognitoIdentityClient.java:503)
                                                                                                     at com.amazonaws.auth.AWSAbstractCognitoIdentityProvider.getToken(AWSAbstractCognitoIdentityProvider.java:198)
                                                                                                     at com.amazonaws.auth.AWSAbstractCognitoIdentityProvider.refresh(AWSAbstractCognitoIdentityProvider.java:314)
                                                                                                     at com.amazonaws.auth.AWSBasicCognitoIdentityProvider.refresh(AWSBasicCognitoIdentityProvider.java:77)
                                                                                                     at com.amazonaws.mobile.user.IdentityManager$AWSRefreshingCognitoIdentityProvider.refresh(IdentityManager.java:142)
                                                                                                     at com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCredentialsProvider.startSession(CognitoCredentialsProvider.java:601)
                                                                                                     at com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCredentialsProvider.getCredentials(CognitoCredentialsProvider.java:388)
                                                                                                     at com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider.getCredentials(CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider.java:442)
                                                                                                     at com.amazonaws.mobile.user.IdentityManager$AWSCredentialsProviderHolder.getCredentials(IdentityManager.java:71)
                                                                                                     at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.invoke(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:4168)
                                                                                                     at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.updateItem(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:1582)
                                                                                                     at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBMapper$SaveObjectHandler.doUpdateItem(DynamoDBMapper.java:1173)
                                                                                                     at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBMapper$2.executeLowLevelRequest(DynamoDBMapper.java:873)
                                                                                                     at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBMapper$SaveObjectHandler.execute(DynamoDBMapper.java:1056)
                                                                                                     at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBMapper.save(DynamoDBMapper.java:904)
                                                                                                     at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBMapper.save(DynamoDBMapper.java:733)
                                                                                                     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
05-25 15:27:26.718 2540-3428/com.test.example D/CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider: Identity id is changed
05-25 15:27:26.718 2540-3428/com.test.example D/CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider: Saving identity id to SharedPreferences
05-25 15:27:26.719 2540-3428/com.test.example D/CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider: Clearing credentials from SharedPreferences
05-25 15:27:26.720 2540-3428/com.test.example D/AWSRefreshingCognitoIdentityProvider: Refreshing token...
05-25 15:27:26.720 2540-3428/com.test.example D/CognitoUserPoolsSignInProvider: cognito-idp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/eu-west-1_pHznonQVB
05-25 15:27:27.329 2540-3428/com.test.example W/MainActivity: run cx: com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentity.model.NotAuthorizedException: Invalid login token. Token expired: 1495725748 >= 1495723433 (Service: AmazonCognitoIdentity; Status Code: 400; Error Code: NotAuthorizedException; Request ID: a97ea5b2-415e-11e7-9bf5-c9c8136baadf)
05-25 15:27:27.329 2540-3428/com.test.example D/AWSMobileClient: AWS Mobile Client is OK
```

Comment: Did you solve the issue? I am having the same problem and I do not know how to fix it! Pls give me some help

Comment: @Onivas did you find a solution? still having this problem.

Comment: @tipsfedora the only solution that I founded is, when I get the error `NotAuthorizedException` means that the token has expired so I am going to call Cognito `getSessionInBackground(authenticationHandler)`to refresh it, and set the new session on `AuthenticationHandler.onSuccess` callback method

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach would be to use your RefreshToken to retrieve new identity/access tokens. I know that in the cognito-javascript SDK the session object does that for you  automatically.